# Kotlin - Coroutines cause heavy CPU usage with DefaultDispatcher after migration to Kotlin 1.3

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, java.util.concurrent, kotlin-coroutines

I have been using the experimental versions of Kotlin coroutines under high concurrency for a long time, and the performance has always been excellent. The main logic could be simplified to the code below:

```
// works fine in kotlin 1.2 with 3000+ QPS for a 40-core host
launch {
  // running in ForkJoinPool.commonPool() by default
  // non-blocking IO function
  val result = supendFunction()
  doSomething(result)
}
```

However, after I updated kotlin to 1.3, and migrated to the formal version of coroutines, like this

```
// kotlin 1.3 version
GlobalScope.launch {
  // running in DefaultDispatcher
  // non-blocking IO function
  val result = supendFunction()
  doSomething(result)
}
```

The CPU usage rises from 2% to 50% without any exception or error thrown. The only difference that I notice is that the coroutines are no longer executed in `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` like before. Instead, they are running in `DefaultDispatcher` threads, like `DefaultDispatcher-worker-30`.

My questions are:

1. Why does it cost so much CPU usage with `DefaultDispatcher`?
2. Why does kotlin 1.3 use `DefaultDispatcher` in place of `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` by default?
3. How to keep the behavior of coroutines just like before 1.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why does it cost so much CPU usage with `DefaultDispatcher`?

It's a completely different implementation that optimizes for several performance targets, for example communication via a channel. It is subject to future improvements.

> 2. Why does kotlin 1.3 use `DefaultDispatcher` in place of `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` by default?

Actually it has been using the `Default` dispatcher all the time, but the resolution of `Default` changed. In the experimental phase, it was equal to the `CommonPool` but now it prefers the custom implementation.

> 3. How to keep the behavior of coroutines just like before 1.3?

Set the `kotlinx.coroutines.scheduler` system property to `off`.

Comment: Thanks! Setting `kotlinx.coroutines.scheduler` to `off` fixed this problem.

Comment: Hello, could you please help me understand / point me in the direction what exactly does setting that property off and / if there is another way (such as using Unconfined dispatcher), to achieve the same thing?